# Right Click macros will only load if personal.xlsb is VISIBLE

Tags: excel, vba

I have following inserted in my personal.xlsb "This Workbook" module:

```
Const strMacro8 = "Compare Sum of Ranges"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   On Error Resume Next
     Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(strMacro8).Delete

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim cBut8

On Error Resume Next

Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(strMacro8).Delete


Set cBut8 = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)


With cBut8
   .Caption = strMacro8
   .Style = msoButtonCaption
   .OnAction = "CompareRanges"
End With

End Sub
```

If the personal.xlsb is hidden when Excel 2016 loads the right click macros do not appear. They will only appear if the personal.xlsb is **visible** when Excel 2016 initially loads.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Please include the VBA code you have in the question; we will need a [mcve] in order to help.

Comment: If you used the CustomUI method, the workbook either needs to be visible, or an add-in.

Comment: Has this changed within Excel 2016 then? Because in Excel 2010 it was not an issue. Also what do you mean by an 'add-in'?

Comment: Does anyone have any comments?